# Detect mprotected memory address

Tags: mmap, mprotect

Is there a function to detect whether a given virtual address mapped by `mmap` is protected by `mprotect`? Accessing such an address will result in segmentation fault if `PROT_NONE` is set. So I'd like to first detect whether they're protected or not.

It's better if I don't need to introduce signal handlers. If there isn't any such function, any other lightweight solution is also fine. Thanks.